# Bootstrap mobile nav not toggling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, nav

Website in question

https://steve-morris.co.uk/

Menu works fine in normal view but when trying to view via a mobile device the nav bar toggle button does  nothing with no errors reported either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included the Bootstrap JS file (`bootstrap.js`), which the mobile nav requires.

Via CDN:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

REF: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn

Comment: Brill thank you, how on earth did I miss that so simple!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Bootstrap JS (`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`) file after your jQuery `<script>` tag[image]

Comment: Brill thank you, how on earth did I miss that so simple!